# Android vs. Java updates

Tags: java, android

I couldn't find this question asked, so I gotta ask: how closely does Android tie it's OS updates to Java's updates? I am currently developing on the latest version of Java (sometimes I'll work out the Java side and then stick it into Android) and I don't want to worry about Android's JVM.

Comment: Read the Android Documentations ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Android SDK requires Java 6 JDK. That alone should say that it doesn't use 7 (yet). http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html

Comment: Ok, that is good to know (and pretty easy to find, ha) but I would still like to know about the first part of my question. Do they just upgrade their JVM willy-nilly?

Comment: @mikbanUtah their JVM does not update with Sun/Oracle Java since it's a completely different one. Android's JVM knows how to deal with the Java language as specified for Java 5 or 6. There is no need to update it every time there is a minor update (like 6u14 -> 6u35) to Sun/Oracle JVM since that's not changing the language or the compiled classes. https://android.googlesource.com/platform/libcore/+log/master is the changelog for the dalvik VM and the core Java implementation (in the luni directory). Big updates to that would require updates to all devices which does not happen for older ones.